# XDocument to dataSet, my nested nodes are getting treated as new tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, ado.net

When looping through elements it thinks the child node is a table, when it should just be a column. I have most of the code working well, until I the code gets to this part: (all of my code is at the bottom)

```
new XElement("TBL_Magic_TripCountries", lstCountry.Items
                                .Cast<ListItem>()
                                .Where(i=> i.Selected)
                              .Select(x => new XElement("CountryCode", x.Value))
                    ),
```

I am receiving a Cannot access destination table 'CountryCode'. I have no idea why this thinks this is a table if its nested within another node.  I am trying to set CountryCode from TBL_Magic_TripCountries, but its not working as I thought. Any help?

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XComment("Created: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()),
            new XElement("Trips",
                new XElement("TBL_TripDetails",
                    new XElement("DepartureDate", txtDepartureDate.Text),
                    new XElement("ReturnDate", txtReturnDate.Text),
                    new XElement("TripRecommendation", tripRecommend),
                    new XElement("TripRecommendationComment", txtTripRecommendComment.Text),
                    new XElement("TripFavouriteThing", txtLikeMostComment.Text)
                  ),
                  new XElement("TBL_Magic_TripCountries", lstCountry.Items
                                .Cast<ListItem>()
                                .Where(i=> i.Selected)
                              .Select(x => new XElement("CountryCode", x.Value))
                    ),
                     new XElement("TBL_Cities", lstCities.Items
                                .Cast<ListItem>()
                                .Select(x => new XElement("City", x.Text))),)

               ));
```

...

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xDoc.CreateReader());
            string StrConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(StrConn);

            SqlBulkCopy blkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                BulkCopyTable(dt, blkcopy);
            }
```

**EDIT** my XML looks like this before I start putting it in the dataset

```
<!--Created: 8/4/2010 8:28:10 AM-->
<Trips>
  <TBL_TripDetails>
    <DepartureDate>2/2/2010</DepartureDate>
    <ReturnDate>2/2/2010</ReturnDate>
    <TripTypeA>1</TripTypeA>
    <TripTypeB>2</TripTypeB>
    <PurposeOfTrip>vacation</PurposeOfTrip>
    <RegionID>2</RegionID>
    <OverallRating>0</OverallRating>
    <SupplierID>3</SupplierID>
    <SupplierComment>great supplier</SupplierComment>
    <FoodRating>0</FoodRating>
    <CulinaryComments></CulinaryComments>
    <RecommendRestaurant>false</RecommendRestaurant>
    <AttractionDisappoint>false</AttractionDisappoint>
    <TripRecommendation>false</TripRecommendation>
  </TBL_TripDetails>
  <TBL_Magic_TripCountries>
    <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
    <CountryCode>CND</CountryCode>
  </TBL_Magic_TripCountries>
  <TBL_Cities>
    <City>New York</City>
    <City>Ottawa</City>
    <City>Las Vegas</City>
  </TBL_Cities>
  <TBL_Magic_TripTransportation>
    <TransportType>3</TransportType>
    <TransportType>4</TransportType>
  </TBL_Magic_TripTransportation>
</Trips>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain this is the cause, but

```
lstCountry.Items 
    .Cast<ListItem>() 
    .Where(i=> i.Selected) 
    .Select(x => new XElement("CountryCode", x.Value))
```

retruns an IEnumerable<XElement> and would be interpreted by the dataset as an element with multiplicity of 0..∞. Datasets will translate that element as a table internally because that's how datasets handle nested relationships. I'm not sure if you'd end up with two tables ("TBL_Magic_TripCountries" associated with your main table and then "CountryCode" associated with it) or a single table "TBL_Magic_TripCountries" with CountryCode as the only column. It's been too long since I dealt with auto-schema-generated datasets.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying, unfortunately I can't figure out how to fix this with the code I have.  Maybe I am better off using XmlDocument instead of XDocument. :(  If you have any other way let me know

Comment: You'll have the same problem whether using XDocument or XmlDocument because either way, your XML structure will be the same. The problem is that datasets kick nested elements into a related-table structure. You can navigate it using the dataset relationship methods, but it'll be a table internally.

Comment: hmm, so in my example how would I insert into TBL_Magic_TripCountries with Country codes, if it thinks its a tabel internally?  thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look into the metadata for the table. Since it's nested XML, there could be a column added to the table that forms the relationship to the outer table (in this case "TBL_Magic_TripCountries"). Whether there's a key column or not, the actual insert is a simple matter of adding values into the table "CountryCodes".